# Authentication - Login Credentials exposed in Chome developer tools

Tags: authentication, password-protection

I was asked about how does it possible to have the login credentials (username and password) on the client side to be secure and to not be shown in Chrome developer tools network tab. There are lots of answers out there saying that it is not possible since it's on the client side, as long as if we are using HTTPS, attackers won't be able to view the data flow from client to server side in plain text.

So, I tried to go to some banking websites and inspected the network flow, I found out that the username and password are both looked like they are encrypted, hashed or encoded. One of the banking websites is using OAuth 1.0 which I am not familiar with. I am wondering how does it possible to not show the credentials in plain text. What are the technologies they usually use?

Answer (score 0):

Often the most basic form of credential transfer is the Basic authorisation scheme, where the username and password are combined and then base64 encoded, and then sent in the `Authorization` HTTP header of a request, e.g. in JavaScript, set the `Authorization` header to:

```
Basic + ' ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
```

Note the ':' between the username and password.

See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).